# Java Composite backgroundimage with relative path

Tags: java, image, background, swt, relative-path

I'm new to Java and I want to add a background image to a Composite. I can only use SWT, no JFace. I'm using eclipse indigo IDE (3.8) and when I want to set a background image, first I initialize an Image class to an image object, but when I press CTRL + SPACE to help choosing the constructor, I have 5 different constructors. I don't know what to choose.

I must use a relative path. The package has the following structure:

```
org.mypackage.program //the package name
org.mypackage.program/src/org.mypackage.program //the plugin-project automated created classes
org.mypackage.program/src/views // all views

org.mypackage.program/car_image.jpg // the image what I would set in background
org.mypackage.program/views/View.java // the class where I want to set the background
```

This is what I made, but it's not working:

```
Image image = new Image(Display.getCurrent(),  this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("car_image.jpg"));
compImage.setBackgroundImage(image);
```

I'm new to OOP too, I programmed only structured/module programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try below code:-

Please note, how the relative path is mentioned

`.\\src\\org\\mypackage\\program\\car_image.gif`

Here src is the root folder of application.

---

```
package org.mypackage.program;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
public class Demo {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Display display = new Display();
            Shell shell = new Shell(display);
            Image img;
            shell.setMaximized(true);
            img= new Image(display,".\\src\\org\\mypackage\\program\\car_image.gif");
            Composite comp= new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
            comp.setBackgroundImage(img);
            shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
            shell.open();
            while (!shell.isDisposed())
            {       
                if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                {         
                    display.sleep();       
                }     
            }     
            display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try the Graphics way that enables you to draw an Image from a starting point (x,y) of your Component.You can scale of course your Image so that it fits the space you want to cover with your image with a specific scale method of Image object.An example:

```
package org.mypackage.program;

//your imports here

public class MyClassName extends JFrame{

public Image myImg;
public int startingX = 0,startingY = 0,newWidth = 300,newHeight = 300;

public static void main(String[] args){
    MyClassName frame = new MyClassName();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public MyClassName(){
    super("JFrame title")

    myImg = Toolkit().getDefaultToolkit().getImage(MyClassName.class.getResource("org/mypackage/program/car_image.jpg"));
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    shell.setMaximized(true);

    myImg = myImg.getScaledInstance(newWidth,newHeight,0);

    Composite comp= new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE){

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            g.drawImage(myImg, startingX, startingY, this);
        }

    };


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> image path set Dynamic or Relative using swt/jface application

---

```
Button btnNewButton = new Button(parent, SWT.NONE);
//Absolute path never use
//btnNewButton.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\Bharat\\Icon\\uncheck.png"));
btnNewButton.setImage(ResourceManager.getPluginImage("RCP_Demo", "icons/delete.png"));
btnNewButton.setBounds(18, 370, 68, 23);
```

---

```
/////Launching time your application can not generate some image related problem 

1)Control: Drag and drop Button control
2)Add image to Button control 
3)select image chooser property and click plugin resource radiobutton
4)select your project,select your image folder after set image to button
```

programmatically useful this answer....have a nice day....thanks